# User Access Permissions

Tags: php, database, oop, logic

I am trying to figure out the best way to configure my DB / check user permissions to give them access to certain site content. 
Our product is essentially like Udemy or some other online teaching platform. We have multiple instructors that can have multiple courses. A user signs up and gets access to certain courses. 
What is a way that I can configure the logic so that a user can only see the courses they are signed up for and instructors can only see the courses they are teaching. 
Thank you!

Comment: You should better look at available Permission-Systems. There is so much around this topic that it hardly can be covered in an answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you have a database table with users and a database table with courses.

Add [associative tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity) for your teaching and student_on relationships.

Then you can do something along the lines of:

```
SELECT course.name, course.id 
    FROM student_on, course 
    WHERE (student_on.student_id = ? AND student_on.course_id = course.id)
;
```